# How do I send a free-to-play game to a friend within Steam

Tags: steam

I'm playing a free-to-play game. I want to recommend the game to a friend. I select the game from my game library. I navigate to the store page. I click on Share button. Steam provides me three options: Facebook, Twitter, Reddit. However, my friend doesn't use any of these services afaik.Does Steam provide some way of sharing the game as a private Steam message? I'd like to avoid opening the web browser to get the store page URL. Also, it would be nice if Steam told my friend that I'm trying to share a game and not just post a random imgurl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click anywhere on the game's store page, select "Copy Page URL".

Comment: Nice! After pasting the link to a private Steam message a preview is shown. The next best thing to actually having a button. :)